# Nodejs not sending http requests inside File ReadStream

Tags: node.js, events, request, fs

I'm having a very strange error where my http requests aren't sending at all. Once I send the request it just stops executing. I'm ingesting a CSV file through a `ReadStream` and sending requests inside the emitter listening blocks. If I try to send the request outside the emitters it can send fine, but I need to POST data from the file so it has to be sent within them (unless there's a way to export the data I don't know about.

Code:

```
const buffer = multipart.parse(event, true).fileName.content;
    const file = stream.Readable.from(buffer);

    let events;

    file.pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
            events = parseEvents(event, results);
            console.log("sending request");
            request({method: 'POST', url: 'https://httpbin.org/anything', json: {hello: 'world'}}, function (err, response, body) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(response);
                console.log(body);
            });
            console.log("finished request");
        })
        .on('error', error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Before you say, I've also tried all kinds of requests. Using got, Axios, and request I've done awaits and tried to process it that way. I actually can get the promise but if I await it nothing happens. It's also not stuck in an infinite loop or anything because when put in a for loop it tries it every time and just always returns nothing.

For more info: The console gets the "sending request" log and then "finished request" and that's it. If I go the promise route, it doesn't even log the "finished request".

Comment: 1. Do you have a full runnable sample with example code and example data? 2. How much CSV data do you have? I'm wondering if this could be as simple as a starvation problem. Does it work if you try a small 3 or 4 line sample?

Comment: I have tried you request call on my side and i get a response. Your code is ok for the request. So, if code is executed, you should have a response. If you don't get response, that can indicate your code is not executed. 
Have you tried execute the end handler in a try catch?

Comment: @RichardWheeldon The CSV is only about 8 lines so definitely isn't an issue

Comment: @Alaindeseine yes and the catch didn't catch anything

Comment: Where does `request` come from? Note that you are writing 'finished request' to stdout regardless of what happens with the request. You presumably want that inside the callback for `request`.

Comment: @yourknightmares Can you provide either csv function or Tell waht csv packa you use?

Comment: and also parseEvents function

Comment: First of all, the nodejs `request` package has been declared deprecated more than two years ago so perhaps you should use something else. Second: You are logging "finished request" without actually awaiting the request being finshed. Nonetheless, it should print something, once the request is actually finished. The code per se looks fine. Does the process end immediately after "finished request" is logged or does it keep running?

Comment: Where do you declare the variables `results` and `event`?

Comment: The program may have just ended before the request could execute the callback. Try to understand how promises work and how to convert a callback into promises. Then only do async functions and await all promises in your high level code.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, url is not an option for http.request(), nor is json:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback

Comment: Probably OP is using the npm[`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package, which supports those options. Still, even if he is using `http.request`, with `console.log(err)` it should at least print some error message ...

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an async issue. After you fire your request, your code executes the next line rather than waits for the response and thats why you see the logs for `sending` and `finished`. Not sure how you implemented the promise solution before, and without seeing the rest of your code it would be hard to debug but I assume something like this *should* work.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    file.pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
        .on('end', () => {
            events = parseEvents(event, results);
            console.log("sending request");
            request({method: 'POST', url: 'https://httpbin.org/anything', json: {hello: 'world'}}, function (err, response, body) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(response);
                console.log(body);
                resolve(body);
            });
            console.log("finished request");
        })
        .on('error', error => {
            reject(error);
            console.log(error);
        })
});
```

Then wherever you are returning the promise to you can call `.then(() => { //do stuff })`

Comment: Even if the async request is not awaited, the callback should still be executed, once the request is finished. Thus Something -- ie either an error or a response -- should be printed.